# How to Access PHP File in Separate Folders

Tags: php

I'm trying to link a website system in php, and I encountered a problem when organizing sub folders. For example, I have a php file in the directory path C:/Demo/Subfolder/index.php, and it has a php include function that links to another php file in C:/Demo/header.php (by using the backing out of folders tool). Then my header.php is linking to an image. The image is in C:/Demo/image.png (same folder as header).

The code for index.php:

```
<?php
include("../header.php");
?>
```

The code for header.php:

```
<img id="icon" src="image.png">
```

When I open up header.php, it shows the image.

When I open up index.php, it can't find the image. This is because it is trying to find the image using the directory C:/Demo/Subfolder/image.png based off of the location of index.php rather than the location of header.php.

How do I access the image in both header.php and index.php without copying it over or moving it around?

Comment: You can use absolute path... Do you familiar with absolute and relative path?

Comment: @orbit I tried absolute path and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
<img id="icon" src="/image.png">
```

If you use without `/` the code will take the same folder where you call...

Comment: I tried it and it worked!  A simple slash solved this entire problem, I couldn't ask for anything better.

Answer (score 0):

it is better you use direct Address

```
include_once(addslashes(realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])).((DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '/') ? '/' : '\\\\')."Folder example/header.php");


////defining CONST for recognition your Operation System  is windows or linux or mac USE / OR \....
define('DS', ((DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '/') ? '/' : '\\\\'));
define('_Site_PATH_', addslashes(realpath(dirname(__FILE__))) . DS );

<img id="icon" src="_Site_PATH_."Demonstration".DS."Folder-example".DS."image.png"">
```